# Create custom sub-command for Docker

Tags: docker, git, alias

For Git user can create [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)

```
git config --global alias.co checkout
git co master
```

If Git cannot find build-in subcommand it looks for `git-SUBCOMMAND` executable in PATH

```
echo -e '!/bin/bash\necho I love Git' >/usr/local/bin/git-love
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/git-love
git love
```

Is it possible to make something similar with Docker?